# ReactPlayer starts at given timestamp that immediately jumps to random timestamp

Tags: reactjs, react-player

So I'm using the ReactPlayer component to play a YouTube video given a timestamp. It starts the video at the timestamp specified in the URL and then immediately jumps to a random timestamp.

```
                   <ReactPlayer
                      controls={true}
                      height={'175px'}
                      playing={isOpen}
                      style={{ borderRadius: '5px', overflow: 'hidden' }}
                      url={videoURL}
                      width={'350px'}
                    />
```

When I do console.log(videoURL) right above the component the resulting URL is correct. Is there a bug with ReactPlayer?

It plays the right video, just the wrong timestamp. But again it starts at the right timestamp and then moves to some random point before or after the timestamp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? How?